# How to pass component as prop to another component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to pass a component (lets say component B) as prop to another component (lets call it component A) and show component B inside Component A in Vue.js:

html:

```
<compA title="Title By Mazoo" content={compB}></compA>
```

js:

```
Vue.component('compA', {
    template: '<div>{{content}}</div> ',
    props: {
       content: ''
    }
});

Vue.component('compB', {
    template: '<div> Various html tags</div> ',

});
```

I know the code above is wrong, In React I can do it like this easily:

```
<compA title="My title" content={<compB />} />

class compA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    {this.props.content}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

class compB extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                   Lots of HTML tags, etc
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need [`slots`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html). Define a slot in `compA` and then include `compB` as child of `compA`:

```
Vue.component('compA', {
    template: '<div><slot></slot></div> '
});

Vue.component('compB', {
    template: '<div> Various html tags</div>',
});
```

In your template:

```
<div id="app">
   <comp-a><comp-b></comp-b></comp-a>
</div>
```